# Eslint, how can I ignore the whole module without any failure?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Having in `.eslintignore`:

```
**/*.ts
```

I get this

```
Error: All files matched by '.' are ignored.
```

I want to ignore this error, how can I do this? My goal is just to disable eslint for a submodule

I have directory structure:

```
root:
  .eslintignore
  submodule:
    .eslintignore
```

- I tried in `root/.eslintignore`: `submodule/**`

Comment: You are ignoring all TS files by now. Did you try `**/submodule` or relative path `./submodule`?

Comment: yes, kinda, I updated the question. I just want to ignore the submodule at all

Answer (score 0):

To make eslint ignoring a certain submodule using `.eslintignore` file a glob pattern should be added with a leading forward slash - `/`.

In your case, adding

```
/submodule/**
```

should do the trick.

Adding `.eslintignore` inside nested folders [is not supported](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore#the-eslintignore-file).

Comment: no this doesn't work for me, I'm not sure maybe these are no submodules. how can I check? when I call in the root "yarn lint:all" it scans those modules though

I just tried again - submodules are scanned

Comment: @ArtemPtushkin actually, eslint config and command line arguments may affect this, so it would be nice if you could add them to your question

Comment: it delegates to backstage cli "lint": "backstage-cli repo lint --since origin/main"

Comment: @ArtemPtushkin I am not familiar with backstage-cli, but it seems that it does customise eslint behaviour. In particular, `since` option tries to find changed files and run eslint only for them, my guess is that it effectively ignores other options such as ignored modules and so on. I would suggest to amend your question with all these details.